# Searching Data using Mongoose where not all fields are entered

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on writing search API where users have capability to search for Individuals using combination of fields for ex. (First Name, Last Name, Job Title). If First Name and Title Name is entered, then the search would return all records matching the first name and title. I am looking to optimize my search, so looking for some options/feedback.

The issue I am facing is for any search, not all data may be entered, so If last name is not entered, my search returns no records (based on how I am doing shown below) though I should be searching using First and Job Title. I am having hard time setting up my search query using Mongoose.

One option would be to check if the data is entered and then build my query on the fly; however, using Mongoose, I tried creating my query and that approach didn't work.

Here's what I have now
Individual.find (
{
first: first,
last: last,
title: title
})

I tried building this as a string based on data entered and then passing

query = {
first: first,
last: last,
title: title
}) but returns all record no matter what is entered/how the query is build and inserted find(query).

Appreciate any feedback on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont pass last if its not there.

```
 var search_options = {};
 if(first)search_options.first = first;
 if(last)search_options.last = last;
 if(title)search_options.title = title;
 Individual.find (search_options);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried as you suggested and was able to resolve my issue.